# Where are the input fields of joomla registration form?

Tags: joomla

I am looking for detecting where are the input fields of joomla 1.7 registration form.
I want to make some changes but i cant detect the file which those input field are. I spent 4-5 hours searching but no luck !!!!

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you using Joomla 1.7? Upgrade, upgrade, upgrade, oh and did I mention upgrade? Joomla 1.7 is old and no longer supported. A lot of security bugs, general issue and new features were introduced in Joomla 2.5 to get yourself on that version. There shouldn't be a problem upgrading in regards to extension compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Please See This file
components\com_users\models\forms\registration.xml